# Where do you store Java .class files, conventionally?

Tags: java, .class-file

I have a Java src folder in which I store my .java files. I then compile them using Terminal and end up getting .class files in the same directory. This doesn't necessarily bother me, but I've never seen that being done professionally.

By professional convention (if there exists one), in what folder in a project's directory should you store compiled .class files?

Comment: Usually? "bin" or "build", and then into a container - a jar or a war or a ear file.

Comment: Worth mentioning, sorry, that I'm a student who hardly needs the .class files beyond running them immediately after compilation. I don't require them being in a professional archive file, but was just curious as to convention on where they are usually stored.

Comment: Profressionally, you use an IDE and/or a build tool like Maven/Gradle, which places them in a different folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're not familiar with it, you should look into the subject of the [Java classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29). I can remember finding this confusing when I first started programming in Java.

There is a defined search path for .class files in Java; when you run `java -cp blahblahblah` that sets the classpath. `java -jar blahblahblah.jar` opens a [JAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) and the .jar file's manifest may dictate the classpath. The default classpath is in the current directory.

Usually you put Java classes in packages in a hierarchical directory structure in the filesystem, in which case the Java compiler will also put `.class` files in a corresponding structure.

If you run `javac` from the command line, the [`-d` argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#commandlineargfile) specifies the destination root directory for `.class` files.

A typical project looks like this, assuming your package is called `com.example.foo` and it contains Foo.java and Bar.java:

```
project_dir/
   src/
      com/
         example/
            foo/
               Foo.java
               Bar.java
   bin/
      com/
         example
            foo/
               Foo.class
               Bar.class
```

The java compiler will be executed with `-d bin` as a destination directory, and it will create the `.class` files corresponding to the `.java` files. But the destination doesn't have to be called `bin`; you could call it `Freddy` or `dumbass` if you wanted to, although that would probably confuse people used to `bin` or `build`.

Most of the time when a Java program or library builds, the `.class` files are just a temporary step towards building a .jar file (essentially just a .zip format with a `.jar` extension, containing the .class files and a little bit of metadata), and when you actually run them, Java will use the .jar file if you include it as part of the classpath.