# Visual Studio Code puts .class files in src folder when compiling

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When I compile and run my project, Visual Studio Code automatically generates a .class file for each .java file and puts them in the src folder, but they are already stored in the bin folder. Why are they duplicated?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe misconfigured compiler? Anyway there are better Java IDEs and you should probably look into Gradle.

Comment: By "generates java files" do you mean `.class` files?

Comment: @kaya3 OP wrote "generates a java class for each java", I guess he means "generates a java .class for each .java"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do you store Java .class files, conventionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312368/where-do-you-store-java-class-files-conventionally)

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Kindly let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile `.java` file manually by command `javac name.java`, the .class file will be generated in folder `src`. By default, it's stored in folder `bin` with default setting

```
"java.project.outputPath": "bin"
```

Turn to .vscode/settings.json, check if you've set `src` as the value of `java.project.outputPath`. Change it back to `bin` then `cleaning java language server workspace` from Command Palette.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed code runner from visual studio code extension then this may result in creating a .class file in the same directory.

Disble or uninstall the code runner extension which will solve your probelm.