# When I run my .java projects, the compiler places the .class files in the src folder and in the bin folder

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compilation, output, settings

I'm having a problem with my output settings for my .java programs. Every time I click on the button to run my project, the compiler creates the .class files and throws them into src, while it also throws them into bin. Wouldn't it be right to put these .class files only in bin and leave the src folder "clean" (only with the .java files)? How can I fix this?

I saw a question similar to mine ([Visual Studio Code puts .class files in src folder when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945181/visual-studio-code-puts-class-files-in-src-folder-when-compiling)), but the settings are correct, but the error is still there. My VS Workspace: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONPIJ.png

Comment: I **strongly** urge you to use maven for building your project. As you have discovered, the native Java tooling can be a bit challenging to use.

Comment: If you're using `javac` directly (or otherwise manually specifying the command line), then use the `-d` option to specify the output directory. But you should pretty much always use a build tool for any non-trivial Java project. Two common build tools in the Java ecosystem are Maven and Gradle (though others exist) and VS Code has extensions for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be seen by screenshots that you are using *CodeRunner* to execute the code, so the `.class` file will be generated directly in the same level of the script file.

Please use the [Java extension package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) to execute the script, so that the `"java.project.outputPath": "bin"` settings will be used.

[image]

The verification method is to delete all the existing `.class` files, and then use Java extension toexecute the script. You will see that the `class` file is generated under the `bin` folder.

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial*

*Of course, I also suggest that you do not use CodeRunner first. Only the official extensions in the early stage will avoid a lot of trouble. Because there are many settings and configurations that are brought about by official extensions, CodeRunner only uses commands to run scripts.*